# Is "no similar event have previously occurred" correct?

Tags: nouns

In a [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.01109.pdf), I met the following passage:

> In conclusion, there is little consensus on whether and when AGI will be created, and what will happen after its creation. Anything else would be highly surprising, given that no similar event have previously occurred.

According to [Oxford dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/event), the word "event" can be used only as a countable noun.

Is the last sentence grammatically incorrect, or do I miss something?

Comment: Looks to me like a typo. Should be "has" as far as I can tell.

Comment: [correction: I came across x, not I met].  It could be: no similar event**s** have previously occurred. The s in events is more likely than a verb tense mistake in an Australian text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comments, it's a typo.